# How to plot data one at a time and create a animation in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array of shape [1047,280]. I want to plot every 1047 values i.e., [280] list on the y-axis. I have a (280) list for the x-axis. I want the plot to run in time. Is it possible in python?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate between the different datasets with a for loop, and add a short time delay between each update if needed using Python's time module. However, if you are looking at making simple animations, I would suggest using a module like pygame.

Here is a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = axis.plot(x, y, 'b-')

for phase in np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 100):
    line1.set_ydata(np.sin(0.5 * x + phase))
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

You need to turn on interactive mode to allow for graph updating too, which is done by plt.ion()